# Ansible - Include environment variables from external YML

Tags: environment-variables, ansible

I'm attempting to store all my environment variables in a file called `variables.yml` that looks like so:

```yaml
---
doo: "external"
```

Then I have a playbook like so:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "i can totally echo"
      environment:
          include: variables.yml
          ugh: 'internal'
      shell: echo "$doo vs $ugh"
      register: results

    - debug: msg="{{ results.stdout }}"
```

The result of the echo is `' vs internal'`.

How can I change this so that the result is `'external vs internal'`. Many thanks!

Comment: I *think* you need to add `vars:` and then indent `doo`. Generally speaking, though, you should [use the recommended directory layout](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout).

Comment: Also you should use the `{{ var }}` syntax rather than `$var`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the external variable file called `variables.ext` is structured as follow

```yaml
---
EXTERNAL:
  DOO: "external"
```

than, according [Setting the remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) and  [Load variables from files, dynamically within a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_vars_module.html#examples) a small test could look like

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Load environment variables
    include_vars:
      file: variables.ext

  - name: Echo variables
    shell:
      cmd: 'echo "${DOO} vs ${UGH}"'
    environment:
      DOO: "{{ EXTERNAL.DOO }}"
      UGH: "internal"
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show result] ********
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: external vs internal
```